# Understanding haskells data types and constructors (specifically where you use another data type in a data type)

Tags: haskell, constructor, custom-data-type

As an assignment we were given these data types, and I need to make a function that get a row (`[Cell]`) and returns `Player X`, `Player O` or `Nothing` depending on the row.

```
module TicTacToe where
import Data.Maybe

data Player = X | O deriving Eq
data Cell = E | P Player deriving Eq
data State = Running | GameOver (Maybe Player) deriving Eq

type Size = Int
type Board = [[Cell]]
type Game = (Size, Board, Player, State)
```

```
whoWonOnRow :: [Cell] -> Maybe Player
whoWonOnRow c
    | head c == E && all (== head c) c = Nothing
    | (head c == P X || head c == P O) && all (== head c) c = Just (head c)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

My understanding is that the data type `Cell` can have 2 values: `E` or `P` which is a `Player` data type. Now I don't understand what the problem is because `head c` will be either `E` or a `Player`, so I compare it to `E` and and a `P Player X` and `Y`.

If the first `Cell` is empty (`E`) than we know that nobody won and, we can return `Nothing`. If it's a `Player` than we check that every other `Cell` is also that players. If so `X` or `O` wins, otherwise `Nothing`.

Comment: As a general thumb rule, prefer pattern matching to `head, tail, !!, length, ==` when it makes sense. Compare your attempt with Willem's below. Recall that `head,tail,!!` can make your program crash if the list is empty, while (exhaustive) pattern matching is safe.

Answer (score 4):

`head c` has as type `Cell`, but your `whoWonOnRow` function is supposed to return a `Maybe Player`, not a `Maybe Cell`.

You can implement this with:

```
whoWonOnRow :: [Cell] -> Maybe Player
whoWonOnRow (e@(P x) : cs) | all (e ==) cs = Just x  -- x, not e (head c)
whoWonOnRow _ = Nothing
```